# Handle Kotlin Filter Predicate multiple inner condition

Tags: android, kotlin, filter, kotlin-android-extensions

In the below list of custom objects, I wanted to implement filtering based on some condition by comparing values in ViewModel class

My list would be like this

```
var inputList: MutableList<Person>
```

Person data class is like follows

```
data class Person(val inContact: Boolean, val age: Int, val isFavourite:Boolean .......)
```

Filtering based on condition:

```
val fav = mViewModel.personInContact.value //TRUE or FALSE
val personAge = mViewModel.personAge.value // INT VALUE
```

Now I wanted to consider `inContact` only if `fav` is `true`.

If `fav` is `false`, I do not want to consider `inContact` at all.

So if the filtering list logic is like this, it will always consider `fav` condition.

```
val filteredFinalList = inputList.filter{

            (it. inContact == fav)//how to ignore this check based on fav's value?

            &&

            (it.age >=  personAge)

            && SOME OTHER CONDITIONS PRESENT AS WELL
}
```

How can I consider `(it. inContact == fav)` if only `fav` is `true` and **avoid** if `fav` is `false` in `inputList.filter` ?

Answer (score 1):

From your description, if `fav` is `true`, you want to make sure it is equal to `it.inContact`. If `fav` is `false`, you want the expression to evaluate to `true`, so that the rest of the conditions can be checked. This would come out to:

```
((fav && it.inContact) || !fav)
```

*Either:*

- `fav` is `true` and `fav` is equal to `it.inContact`. Because we already know `fav` is `true`, we will only ever check if `it.inContact` is `true`. Because of that, we don't need to compare the two value, only check that they're both `true`
- `fav` is `false`, thus we want the entire expression to evaluate to `true`. `!fav` will always be `true` at that point, which will make the `||` expression evaluate to `true`.